# How to tweak the variables, which a Lambda expression in Vala captures?

Tags: memory, lambda, vala

**How to capture `this` only weakly in a anonymous function?**

I couldn't find anything in the docs regarding whether (or how) the variables captured by a anonymous function / lambda expression could be tweaked. The problem is that these functions seem to capture all variables from the stack frame, they are created in, at least by default. Particularly, they always capture `this`, which is problematic when using them for signal handlers, because the handlers turn into hard references to `this` then, probably causing reference cycles.

Does Vala have some mechanism on how to prevent lambdas from capturing hard references of `this`? Currently, I'm creating a new class for each signal handler, like `A.Handler`, where I only keep a weak reference to the actual `this` of `A` which I need to reference from inside the handler, but I think this undermines the benefits of lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a lambda, no. The standard approach is this:

```
class Foo : Whatever {

  public Foo {
    unowned Foo unowned_this = this;
    this.bar_signal.connect(unowned_this.bar_handler);
  }
  private void bar_handler() {
    ...
  }
}
```

This doesn't capture a reference to this, but you also cannot capture any other variables.

Comment: With the code you provided, it's still up to us to **(1)** ensure that the `Foo` instance isn't accessed from within `bar_handler` after it's been finalized? Also, **(2)** the reference held by `bar_signal` is *strong*, right?

Comment: 1) The `Foo` instance can be accessed inside the handler, but it's probably a bad idea. The `connect` method returns an id that you can use to disconnect all the signals in the destructor, making it totally deterministic. If you don't, the way Vala cleans up memory means you can't do anything bad, but some properties might be unexpectedly null.
2) No, the reference held by `bar_signal` is weak. If you want it strong, `bar_signal.connect(bar_handler)`.

Comment: Thanks, it's much clearer now, but I got another question left. Please consider [this short code](http://hastebin.com/ijamamineb.vala) I wrote based yours. After the `Foo` instance is finalized, is its reference held by `bar_signal` only set to `null` or also dropped? In other words: Do we have to care about memory leaking if we don't disconnect the signal from its handler explicitly? Does `bar_signal` hold a bunch of `null` references or doesn't it hold anything after the instances are finalized?

Comment: You would care. `bar_signal` will hold a dangling pointer. If you run this under Valgrind, it should produce a use-after-free error.

Comment: Just in case somebody else stumbles over this, don't get confused: Vala [*does*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39038749/1444073) disconnect signal handlers automatically, as far as the utilization of `g_signal_connect_object` allows that.