# Vala: Disconnecting signal handler via Handler ID from class destructor fails - Why?

Tags: vala

I'm trying to get my head around what a good practice for inter-class signals in Vala is. Somehow, there seems to be absolutely no documentation available on this topic. After learning how to [connect signals to handlers weakly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39019211/1444073), the question remains, how that connection is best to be dropped, when the signal handler is destroyed.

Lets consider a simple example. We have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`, where an instance of `Bar` emits a signal `bar_signal`, that is handled by an instance of `Foo`. However, this signal is connected weakly, allowing the `Foo` instance do be deleted, why the connection is still in tact:

```
class Bar : Object {
    public signal void bar_signal();
}

class Foo : Object {
    string tag;
    ulong hid;
    Bar bar;

    public Foo( Bar bar, string tag ) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.bar = bar;
        weak Foo weak_this = this;
        hid = bar.bar_signal.connect( weak_this.handle );
    }

    ~Foo() {
        stdout.printf( "foo finalized\n" );
    }

    private void handle() {
        stdout.printf( "handler: %s\n", tag );
    }
}

public static void main( string[] args ) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo( bar, "x" );
        bar.bar_signal(); // writes "handler: x"
    }                     // foo destroyed at end of block
    bar.bar_signal();     // writes nothing
}
```

According to [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014695/how-to-tweak-the-variables-which-a-lambda-expression-in-vala-captures/39019211?noredirect=1#comment65404521_39019211), the handler reference remains as a dangling pointer in `bar_signal`, after the `Foo` instance is destroyed, because we aren't disconnecting it yet.

I have considered adding a

```
bar.bar_signal.disconnect( handle );
```

the destructor of `Foo`, which works fine.

However, I think that there might be occasions, where `handle` isn't accessible from the destructor, e.g. when the handler is a closure.

**Question:** We also can disconnect the handler from the signal using the return value of the corresponding `connect` call. This works very fine, when done right after the `connect` call for example. But why does it fail in the destructor?

```
~Foo() {
    stdout.printf( "foo finalized\n" );
    bar.disconnect( hid ); // <--!!
}
```

It fails with the following hint:

> GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance '0x8c8820' has no handler with id '1'

---

#### Updates

**Update 1:** Interestingly, the `bar.disconnect( hid )` invocation works, if it is done from within of `Foo`'s `dispose` method. According to the documentation of [`GObject`'s memory management](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-memory.html#gobject-memory-cycles), `dispose` is called right before the object is finalized (which I think corresponds to the destructor in Vala) and **it's intention is to cut all references to other objects.** Notably, as pointed out by @AlThomas, *"signal handlers [...] are not automatically disconnected when the signal handler user data is destroyed."* So why can we disconnect the signal handler from `dispose`, but not when `Foo` is finalized, which is what GObject's documentation [actually recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39038749/1444073)?

The only explanation, that comes to my mind, is that: Contrary to what I've been told before Vala/GLib *do* disconnect the signal handlers on it's own in between of disposing and finalizing the object. However, this sounds quite unlikely to me, so I would really appreciate further clarification.

**Update 2:** Turns out, the above wasn't that wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general note, Vala's signals are an implementation of the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) using GLib's GObject signals. So a good source of information is GLib's own documentation. For example [Signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/signal.html) and [How to create and use signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-signals.html). The latter stating:

> The signal system in GType is pretty complex and flexible: it is possible for its users to connect at runtime any number of callbacks (implemented in any language for which a binding exists) to any signal and to stop the emission of any signal at any state of the signal emission process.

A complex topic needs good documentation and your Vala specific questions help to build up the body of knowledge on this topic.

For your question the most relevant section of the GLib documentation is probably [Memory management of signal handlers](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#signal-memory-management). This section advises:

> While signal handlers are automatically disconnected when the object emitting the signal is finalised, they are not automatically disconnected when the signal handler user data is destroyed...There are two strategies for managing such user data. The first is to disconnect the signal handler (using `g_signal_handler_disconnect()` or `g_signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func()`) when the user data (object) is finalised; this has to be implemented manually. For non-threaded programs, `g_signal_connect_object()` can be used to implement this automatically...The second is to hold a strong reference...The first approach is recommended...

When digging deep in to how Vala works a useful option is the `--ccode` switch with `valac`. If you look at the C code from your program you will see the `foo_construct` function includes a call to `g_signal_connect_object()`. So Vala is using the first approach outlined in the documentation, but of the three function calls suggested Vala is using the automatic one by calling `g_signal_connect_object()`.

There is no need to disconnect manually and this is why you are getting the warning. GLib has already disconnected the signal. The GLib documentation may be a bit confusing here, because part of the manual process has a call that can automatically disconnect.

GLib's documentation on [Object destruction](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-destruction.html) advises "The destruction process of your object is in two phases: dispose and finalize". So presumably the disconnect is done in the dispose stage, but you would have to look at GLib's source code to confirm that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your informative answer, but I'm not really sure how this explains why `g_signal_handler_disconnect` fails when called from the destructor of `Foo`, which indeed indicates that the object is being finalized, at least in my understanding?

Comment: In my quote from the documentation I edited out the sentence on `g_signal_connect_object`. I've edited my answer to include this. Hopefully this explains what you are seeing in your code.

Comment: Great, thanks! This definitely explains the observations. Although I think, you meant *"...automatic way provided by GLib by calling `g_signal_connect_object`"* rather than *"... by calling `g_signal_handler_disconnect`"*, right? Also, I don't quite see in how far Vala is using *"the first approach"*, because as far as I understand now, the *"first approach"* would be to do it manually using `g_signal_handler_disconnect`?

Comment: The first approach talked of in the documentation is to disconnect the signal and it mentions three different function calls to do that. The second approach is "The second is to hold a strong reference on the user data until after the signal is disconnected for other reasons. This can be implemented automatically using g_signal_connect_data()." That was my reading. That was why I said the documentation could appear confusing.