# How does it come that the Gtk examples in Vala documentation don't cause memory leaks?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, gtk, vala

Lets take for instance the *"Synchronizing Widgets"* from [Vala's Gtk+ wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GTKSample#Synchronizing_Widgets). There is a class named `SyncSample`, derived from `Gtk.Window`. This class adds two widgets to itself, namely a `Gtk.SpinButton` and a `Gtk.Scale`. According to the [Wiki page on ownership in Gtk](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Ownership#Establishing_Ownership), this establishes *hard* references from the `SyncSample` to the widgets:

```
using Gtk;

public class SyncSample : Window {

    private SpinButton spin_box;
    private Scale slider;

    public SyncSample () {

        // ...

        spin_box = new SpinButton.with_range (0, 130, 1);
        slider = new Scale.with_range (Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0, 130, 1);
```

Now comes the interesting part:

```
        spin_box.adjustment.value_changed.connect (() => {
            slider.adjustment.value = spin_box.adjustment.value;
        });
        slider.adjustment.value_changed.connect (() => {
            spin_box.adjustment.value = slider.adjustment.value;
        });
```

Closures, which capture the `this` reference in a hard way, are added to those widgets. So effectively, a hard reference to the `SyncSample` object is given to each widget. This already causes cycles of hard references:

- `SyncSample` → … → `Gtk.SpinButton` → … → `SyncSample`
- `SyncSample` → … → `Gtk.Scale` → … → `SyncSample`

But it's not just this: Even if the closures didn't capture a `this` reference (they [*do*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39014695/1444073) capture a hard `this` reference), the `spin_box` and `slider` still remained hard references too, leading us to another loop of hard references:

- `Gtk.SpinButton` → … → `Gtk.Scale` → … → `Gtk.SpinButton`

**Please explain:** Why doesn't this cause memory leaks?!

Answer (score 1):

You write: "Closures, which capture the this reference in a hard way, are added to those widgets. So effectively, a hard reference to the SyncSample object is given to each widget." This is your mistake; if you look at the generated code, you'll see nothing takes a ref on `this`. The generated code uses `g_signal_connect_object`, which keeps a ref on the connected object (the `Gtk.SpinButton` and `Gtk.Scale` in your example) only for the duration of the signal emission, and which disconnects the signal automatically when the connected object is destroyed. But it *does not* take a ref on the `this` object that's connecting to the signal (the `SyncSample` in this case). If it did, that would indeed create a cycle.

If you're sure that `this` will outlive the object you're connecting to, then there's no problem. Otherwise, you need to disconnect from the signal manually (in the Vala destructor) to avoid the signal handler being called with a pointer to a previously-freed `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

*Let me start with a disclaimer: This answer is based on suspicion and empirical observation. Please feel free to comment your opinion on whether it's right or wrong.*

Scroll down for the "take home message".

---

#### The Long Story

I've run a small experiment. What I've done, was to add

```
WeakRef weak_window_ref;
WeakRef weak_slider_ref;
```

to the global scope and

```
weak_window_ref = WeakRef( this );
weak_slider_ref = WeakRef( slider );
```

at the end of `SyncSample`'s constructor.
Furthermore, in the example's `main` routine, I added

```
window = null;
stdout.printf( "window leaked? %s\n", weak_window_ref.@get() != null ? "yes" : "no" );
stdout.printf( "slider leaked? %s\n", weak_slider_ref.@get() != null ? "yes" : "no" );
```

right in-between of the `Gtk.main()` and the `return 0` instructions.

When running this setup, we see that neither the window, nor its widgets are leaked. This is great, because it means that the reference cycle is broken up — somehow.

Now, lets make a tiny modification to the setup: We remove the `Gtk.main()` invocation, that is located right before the `window = null` assignment. You might think, that this shouldn't change the output, should it? Lets see...

> window leaked? yes
>
> slider leaked? yes

So, *this time* the reference cycle is *not* broken up, and leaked in consequence. How can that be? I suppose that [`Gtk.Widget`'s `destroy` signal](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.destroy) and particularly its [default implementation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-destroy) is the answer to that question:

> When a widget is destroyed all references it holds on other objects will be released:
>
> - if the widget is inside a container, it will be removed from its parent
> - if the widget is a container, all its children will be destroyed, recursively

Probably, this signal is emitted by Gtk/Vala when the window is closed. And as it's delegated to the window's widgets, these widgets remove themselves from the window. It's important to notice that the `SyncSample` class nevertheless keeps two hard references (its class members) to its widgets.

**So here comes the suspicion:** The interaction of the window and its widgets, which is triggered by their `destroy` signals, *somehow* (see: *"all references it holds on other objects will be released"*) disconnects the widgets' signals from their handlers. These handlers hold hard references to the `SyncSample` object, because they were defined as closures. So despite of that the hard references from `SyncSample` to its widgets are still intact, the two reference cycles are broken up:

- `SyncSample` → … → `Gtk.SpinButton` <s>→ … → `SyncSample`</s>
- `SyncSample` → … → `Gtk.Scale` <s>→ … → `SyncSample`</s>

Consequently, the window runs out of references and is deleted.

At this point, one might argue: Isn't there a third cycle of hard references,

- `Gtk.SpinButton` → … → `Gtk.Scale` → … → `Gtk.SpinButton`

which should prevent the two widgets from being destroyed? This is a justified question, and again, I do only *suppose* the following: The closures *only* capture the hard reference of the `SyncSample` object, but not the references to `spin_box` and `slider`. These are accessed *transitively* through the `this` reference:

- `Gtk.SpinButton` → <s>`SyncSample` →</s> `Gtk.Scale` → <s>`SyncSample` →</s> `Gtk.SpinButton`

Hence, as soon as the first two cycles are broken up, the widgets are destroyed, which in turn resets `SyncSample`'s reference counter to zero, leading to its destruction.

---

#### Open Questions

*How* do the handlers, which `SyncSample`'s constructor installs on its widgets' signals, get disconnected, when the window's and the widgets' `destroy` signal is triggered?

---

#### The Short Version

Consider the following as a "take home message".

- Probably, it's fine to use closures and hard references to `this` for the callbacks of child widgets e.g. in a window **if** the window is either shown and particularly closed at some later time *or* its `destroy` signal is emitted by some other mechanism.
- Probably, custom container widgets should ensure that the `destroy` implementation releases all references to their child widgets. Maybe this is already ensured by the `Container` class.
- If your custom widget maintains hard references to other classes, which in turn could have hard references to that widget, it might be a good idea to also releases the former additionally when that widget's `destroy` signal is emitted.

Comment: You can also just read the output C sources directly to see exactly what its doing (though barely human readable).

Comment: To answer the open question, all connected signal handlers get removed automatically when any GObject is destroyed. It has nothing to do with GTK+.

Comment: @MichaelC. What exactly do you mean by "destroyed"? I can't see such a signal or method in the [API](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gobject-2.0/GLib.Object) of `GLib.Object`. Probably, you mean that its destructor is called: This would require that there aren't any hard references left on that `Object`, which isn't the case here, is it?

Comment: Keep in mind the "destructor" concept in more complicated in GObject: there is the dispose phase and finalize phase, the combination of which is roughly the same as a C++ destructor.

Indeed, `gtk_widget_destroy` will not cause the object to be disposed/finalized if there are still other references to it hanging around. I would be surprised if connecting to a signal handler causes such a reference to be taken, but I haven't checked the generated code to be sure.

Comment: As for why removing `Gtk.main` changes the result: that's where GTK+ releases its internal references to your widget hierarchy.